# Comparison between native language or cross platform language such as HTML5 for mobile applications

Tags: mobile

After I researched in some websites, I found that it is better to use cross-platform language to write apps.
But, is it good for using HTML5, and is there any tutorial for writing applications for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

It's not better, but it is faster and easier. Android wants Java, iPhone wants Objective C, meanwhile you can fire up e.g. PhoneGap and write everything in JavaScript. Thus, you save time on development, but the application itself will run slower, it will take more work to make it conform to the platform look and feel. As for tutorials, they accompany each individual framework.